# Can we add text to ask users to upload pictures?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know if this was asked before, but about every other comment I see is asking new users to upload examples of pictures so we can see what problems they are having.

Is there some way to ask users when they are asking the question to include any images that would be relevant to the question?

Comment: Good plan. ...I always get a little relieved when I see askers having added images. Makes it easier to start reading. Confronted with a wall of text: I will probably read it if the title instantly makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it will make any difference.

Those that do not post images aren't really thinking ahead before asking. They are flying by the seat of their pants and posting. Text asking them to add images will merely make them stop..... think... and probably prevent them from posting a question.

It's a good idea. I just don't know that it would result in any improvement.

Comment: Mainly agree with you Scott, but if it is not immensely complicated, it would be interesting to try to implement. Something like "will people considering your problem understand easier if you add some images".

Comment: Why so pessimistic, Scott?

Comment: Not pessimistic at all, a realist. People won't do more than the minimum in most instances.

Comment: Maybe a second confirmation to ask if they forgot anything like graphics links, etc? I don't know if that would be annoying, but I get asked if I'm a robot all the time.

Answer (score 2):

There are two areas on the [ask a question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) where this type of reminder could (and I'd argue, should) be included.

When you first open that page, there is an info box on the side of the page that reads:

> ### How To Ask
>
> **Is your question about graphic design?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

In comparison, the info box when [asking a meta question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instructs users to "Provide details. Show examples" instead of "Share your research" -- a wording that is probably more relevant for graphic design.  But something even more specific, like "This is a graphic design site, so include example graphics" would be better.

It won't catch every one -- the info box is somewhat tucked away on the side of the page -- but it might wake up a few people.

On the same page, when the keyboard focus moves to the actual compose-your-question text area, the "**How To Ask**" info box changes to a "**How to Format**" box with a list of common formatting tasks.  But it doesn't mention how to insert images, so new users might not immediately realize that this is a possibility.

The list of formatting suggestions can be customized by site (e.g., other sites include information on formatting code, math equations, etc.).  For graphic design, a mention about how to upload or link-in images seems sensible.  Again, it won't eliminate every *"Can you please upload an example?"* comment, but it should help.